# Is there any way to extract all the frames of a video in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, opencv, frames, android

I am working on an application in which i'm extracting all the frames of a video. I have tried multiple approaches but not able to get any results. So can anyone suggest how to do this?

I have tried OpenCV and MediaMetadataRetriever in android studio.

Comment: try ffmpeg for that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is **Yes** !, you can do that easily using ***[FmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever)*** library.

Add those two lines in your build.graddle under module app:

```
implementation 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever-core:1.0.19'
implementation 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever native:1.0.19'
```

Sync your project.

**Usage:**

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(mUri);
mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST;
// duration of the video
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
int duration = Integer.parseInt(time);
//frame every selected period
int period = 1000000//each 1 second will get 1 frame, if you want more precision, minimise the period 
int len = duration/period;
List<Bitmap> frames = ArrayList();

for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
Bitmap frame = mmr.getFrameAtTime(i * period, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST); // frame at 2 seconds 
frames.add(frame);

}   
    mmr.release();

//here you can do what ever you want from the frames arraylist
for(Bitmap frame: frames){

   //here you can do what ever you want from the frame

}
```